# Text center is off with a few pixels

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning CSS and I found a very odd problem. When I am trying to align a text in the middle of the div it gets off with 1 px for the horizontal axis (Right:82px; Left:81px;) and 2 pixels for the vertical axis (Top:13px; Bottom:11px;). Firstly, I assumed that this might be just a bug coming from the font but after trying a few others the problem was still there. Can someone please explain what is causing the problem and is there a way I can fix it?

```css
#Div_One{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:300px;
  background-color:gray;
}

#Div_Center{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  line-height:40px;
  background-color:gray;
  color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:"Ubuntu";
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="Div_One">
    <div id="Div_Center">
        Random Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well there are no "half pixels", so it may not possible horizontal, but i dont know whats wrong vertical

Comment: if you zoom it, you take size much easier : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRbaxb seems normal to me. indeed , pixel cannot be broken, each browser will round numbers their way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your text in a paragraph. If it's only one text, you can give the paragraph an ID. If it's a lot of text, give all paragraphs with that font a class. If it's all paragraphs, then style paragraphs as follows: set the position to relative and correct with top and left. Don't forget that the line-height also influences the vertical position of your text if it's a paragraph. You could do the same when placing your text between span tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            #Div_One{
              margin:0;
              padding:0;
              width:300px;
              background-color:gray;
            }

            #Div_Center{
              position:relative;
              width:300px;
              line-height:40px;
              background-color:gray;
              color:#000;
              text-align:center;
              font-family:"Ubuntu";
              font-size:20px;
            }
            #myText {
              position:relative;
              top:10px;  
              left:-20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="Div_One">
            <div id="Div_Center">
                <p id="myText">Random Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```